# Representing resultsets in text "tables"

Tags: sql

This may be a strange question, but I'm wondering how users on sites like stackoverflow format the example resultsets when asking / answering questions? Is there a clean and easy way to create something like:

```
 +----------+-------------------+
 | Count(*) | MAX(created_date) |
 +----------+-------------------+
 |   234    |     10-may-14     |
 |   847    |     03-Apr-14     |
 +----------+-------------------+
```

It does a great job at representing everything in plain text, I'm just wondering if everyone takes the time to format that manually? Or is that an export option for some sort of database software? Something tells me I'm showing my inexperience here haha.

Comment: Yes, it is called a keyboard.

Comment: Thanks OldProgrammer, really schooling us young ones. I half expected this answer but figured I would ask anyways.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I found what I was looking for! This simple tool lets you mock up your table/data in excel, then copy/paste in the default tab delimited format. It then converts it into  the ASCII style table seen in my question. Worth a bookmark in my opinion.

http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Your example is:

```
 +----------+-------------------+
 | Count(*) | MAX(created_date) |
 +----------+-------------------+
 |   234    |     10-may-14     |
 |   847    |     03-Apr-14     |
 +----------+-------------------+
```

I think the following is a pretty desirable format:

```
Count(*) MAX(created_date)
    234      10-may-14
    847      03-Apr-14
```

(The only improvement is to represent the dates in ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format. ;-)

To get this format, just prepend each row with four spaces.  That creates the background shading and the fixed-width font.  You can also omit the first four spaces and just type in what you want:

Count(*) MAX(created_date)
    234      10-may-14
    847      03-Apr-14

Oh.  That looks ugly.  Select the three lines and click on the `{}` just above the input box and the four spaces are added automagically.

Comment: Thanks. Although I wasn't asking regarding stackoverflow formatting specifically, more along the lines of the text borders. Your solution works for this small set, but with a bunch of columns (especially those with long column names) I always find it to be a pain to tab everything to *just* the right alignment. Of course, pretty formatting isn't necessary to convey an idea/example, but they look so nice I wanted to see if there was an easy way. I guess just nice people with some time on their hands! Now I'm wondering if I couldn't whip up some sort of excel macro to add that style formatting..